# Accessing External Services

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node outside of my Kubernetes cluster running a web service that I need to access from inside a Pod. The documentation mentions using a Service without a Selector here:
http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/

So I created a service like so:

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 8082,
                "targetPort": 8082
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then created my endpoint:

```
{
    "kind": "Endpoints",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "subsets": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                { "ip": "128.115.198.7" }
            ],
            "ports": [
                { "port": 8082 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Test App:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ta-p
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: ta-c
    image: "centos:7"
    command: ["/bin/bash","-c", "sleep 100000"]
  nodeSelector:
    node: "kube-minion-1"
```

Remote into Pod doing:

```
kubectl exec ta-p -c ta-c -i --tty -- /bin/bash
```

Then whenever I `kubectl exec` into a container in my pod and try to ping or curl my-service like so:

```
curl http://my-service/api/foo
```

it times out. I have verified DNS is setup and working correctly. However, I have even tried using the IP address directly bound to the service:

```
curl http://10.0.124.106:8082/api/foo
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You still need to specify a port with a service. I think `curl http://my-service/api/foo` will try to use port 80 by default, but you've opened 8082

Comment: Yea, I tried that still no luck. I know all my Kube nodes can reach the external service node, because I can curl from any of those node and reach the external service fine. However,  curling in side the Pod just times out. I am using version 1.2 alpha-6 if that matters.

Answer (score 5):

Note: A better way to solve this now is using `externalName` on the Service. This will add a `CNAME` record to the internal Kubernetes DNS:
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/network/service-external-name.md

This feature was shipped with Kubernetes 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was going on. It appears my Kube cluster must have been in an awkward state. I restarted the cluster and it is now working...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the names on ports for both service and endpoints are the same.

```
{
    ...
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "my-service",
        "port": 8082
      }
    ]
    ...
}
```